# Is there a closed form to this summation?

Tags: summation, combinations, factorial, closed-form

I cannot get a closed form for
 $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{m} \frac{(m+r) !}{(m-r)! (2 r)!}$ ‘
Does anyone have any idea on what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sum is the Fibonacci number $F_{2 m+1}$.

Comment: Do you have a proof for this?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{(m+r)!}{(m-r)!(2r)!}= {{m+r} \choose {2r}}$$

Comment: Do you have a proof for this?

Comment: I’m not saying the series equals that, but rather you can simplify $a_n$.

Comment: Sorry yes I understood your answer. I meant to comment this on the other answer. Apologies and ty for the help :)